# django1.4.0:ImportError: No module named base

Tags: django

Now I have a problem as the title. Here is my environment:

- OS:ubuntu 10.10
- Python:2.6.6
- Django:1.4 pre-alpha

Before, I installed Django 1.1.1 for the [The Django Book](http://new.djangobook.com/en/2.0/). Today , I removed Django 1.1.1 by cmd: `sudo apt-get install --purge python-django`, then get the latest version of 1.4 pre-alpha.

when I followed the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) on the docs.djangoproject.com, and execute cmd: `python manage.py shell`, it comes some error and the infomation like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 422, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 361, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 355, in handle
        return self.handle_noargs(**options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 46, in handle_noargs
        from django.db.models.loading import get_models
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 23, in load_backend
        return import_module('.base', backend_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named base
```

Could some guys tell me how solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably because You have no full path for your DB backend. You probably have:

```
'ENGINE': 'sqlite3',
```

instead of:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call manage.py from the folder where settings.py is located: ../manage.py shell
(In case using sqlite3)
(And djando 1.4)